# Run a node.js app with lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, node.js

I'm currently hosting some websites on my server, and I use Lighttpd for this.

Now I'm currently developing a web application using Node.js and I'd like to be able to create vhosts which would point to the Node.js application.

Let's say, I'd like test.com:80 to point out to myserver.org:3000. I don't believe it is possible to directly use Node.js for this since the port 80 is already registered on the machine. So the only way I'm seeing is using some kind of reversed proxy with Lighttpd. But I don't know how and with what I'm going to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you enable lighttpd's `mod_proxy` first.  To have all of the requests for `test.com` sent to the Node.js backend (assuming it's on localhost; correct?):

```
$HTTP["host"] == "test.com" {
  proxy.server  = ( "" => (
    ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 3000 )
  ) )
}
```